# Copy and Paste over seperate excel sheet (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently trying to paste under a location on a separate excel sheet that I have already pasted to with the following code.

```
Dim Lastrow As Integer
Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:E" & Lastrow).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E1")
```

I need to paste again but underneath what I pasted already.

Comment: Can't you just find the last used row on Sheet2 after doing the copy, and then paste below that?

Comment: do not use "ActiveSheet" ... if you happen to click on a worksheet tab while the code is executing, the clicked worksheet will become ActiveSheet and mess things up  ... refer to worksheets by name as you have done in the next line